# How to make a complex layout in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I'm an iOS developer. I'm new at Android and I'm struggling with the layout I want to achieve.

I did this app on iOS and I'm trying to replicate it on Android, here's my layout on Xcode :

[image: My layout on Xcode]

On Xcode I have a simple view with labels inside. Those labels widths and heights are set depending on the parent view's width/height and adjusted with multipliers.

Can I achieve this relative layout? Constraint layout?

Comment: this is horizontal or portrait mode in android device

Comment: The app will be only in horizontal mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only very brief exposure to iOS development, but I do recall that the layout builder involved a lot of "connecting" individual views to each other and "constraining" how they should be positioned.

Probably the most-similar thing to this in Android would be `ConstraintLayout`. This viewgroup allows you to specify `Constraint`s for each child (e.g. "position this view's right edge at the left edge of this other view" etc). You can also use "weight" to say e.g. "this view should take 80% of the space, and this other view should take 20% of the space".

Here's my ConstraintLayout equivalent of your example:

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:padding="24dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="O"
        android:background="@drawable/corners"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/two"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/five"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="O"
        android:background="@drawable/corners"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/one"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/three"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/six"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="4"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="O"
        android:background="@drawable/corners"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/two"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/four"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/six"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="O"
        android:background="@drawable/corners"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/three"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/six"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="S"
        android:background="@drawable/corners"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/one"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/six"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="CHUI"
        android:background="@drawable/corners"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/two"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/five"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Great that's exactly what I needed, thanks a lot :) So just to clarify, setting width and height as 0dp will by default spread my elements evenly (considering that I constraint them together and to the left and right of the container), and if I want something more custom I had the weight param ?

Comment: In `ConstraintLayout`, using a width or height of `0dp` means "make me as wide as I have to be to satisfy my constraints". So `0dp` width is often combined with both left+right constraints. If you hook a bunch of views up together in a "chain" (e.g. one<->two<->three<->four in my example), then the default is for them to split the space evenly, with weight overriding that. The Google developer doc on ConstraintLayout is pretty good: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/